# macOS 10.13.6 running WireShark 3.6.21 sudden crashes

Tags: macos, crash, wireshark

WireShark 3.6.21 runs without a problem on Macbook using macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra.  It suddenly crashes, but relaunching WireShark causes it to run again without a problem until again a sudden crash.  First part of crash report, below.  Any help welcome.

```
Process:               Wireshark [1584]
Path:                  /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark
Identifier:            org.wireshark.Wireshark
Version:               3.6.21 (3.6.21)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Wireshark [1584]
User ID:               [•]

Date/Time:             2024-03-01 18:39:18.320 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G66)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        44A2E51B-8D3D-8570-C840-[•]

Sleep/Wake UUID:       E0492A74-CB88-4709-98B7-[•]

Time Awake Since Boot: 9600 seconds
Time Since Wake:       81 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing

Application Specific Information:
Wireshark 3.6.21 (v3.6.21-0-gddd4e7d3029f)
 
Compiled (64-bit) using Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1), with Qt 5.15.3,
with libpcap, without POSIX capabilities, with GLib 2.76.6, with zlib 1.2.11,
with Lua 5.2.4, with GnuTLS 3.8.3 and PKCS #11 support, with Gcrypt 1.10.2, with
MIT Kerberos, with MaxMind DB resolver, with nghttp2 1.56.0, with brotli, with
LZ4, with Zstandard, with Snappy, with libxml2 2.11.5, with libsmi 0.4.8, with
QtMultimedia, with automatic updates using Sparkle, with SpeexDSP (using system
library), with Minizip.
 
Running on Mac OS X 10.13.6, build 17G66 (Darwin 17.7.0), with Intel(R) Core(TM)
i7-2720QM CPU @ 2.20GHz (with SSE4.2), with 16384 MB of physical memory, with
GLib 2.76.6, with zlib 1.2.11, with Qt 5.15.3, with libpcap 1.8.1 -- Apple
version 79.20.1, with c-ares 1.19.1, with GnuTLS 3.8.3, with Gcrypt 1.10.2, with
nghttp2 1.56.0, with brotli 1.0.9, with LZ4 1.9.4, with Zstandard 1.5.5, with
libsmi 0.4.8, with LC_TYPE=C, binary plugins supported (0 loaded).
 

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libgcrypt.20.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 11.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   dyld                            0x0000000113d0e24a __abort_with_payload + 10
1   dyld                            0x0000000113d0dbbc abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 89
2   dyld                            0x0000000113d0dbe9 abort_with_payload + 9
3   dyld                            0x0000000113ce1482 dyld::halt(char const*) + 354
4   dyld                            0x0000000113ce15a9 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 170
5   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff548d2292 dyld_stub_binder + 282
6   ???                             0x0000000110dfd2c0 0 + 4578071232
7   libgcrypt.20.dylib              0x0000000110d6314f _gcry_md_block_write + 351 (hash-common.c:193)
8   libgcrypt.20.dylib              0x0000000110d5a118 _gcry_md_setkey + 744 (md.c:977)
9   libgcrypt.20.dylib              0x0000000110d39889 gcry_md_setkey + 89 (visibility.c:1353)
10  libwsutil.13.dylib              0x000000011101c161 ws_hmac_buffer + 81
11  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109256870 dissect_quic + 7488 (packet-quic.c:2423)
12  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x00000001092578e1 dissect_quic_heur + 529
13  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac8d4c dissector_try_heuristic + 380 (packet.c:2864)
14  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109481009 decode_udp_ports + 905 (packet-udp.c:712)
15  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109482e22 dissect + 3810 (packet-udp.c:1267)
16  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109481a13 dissect_udp + 19 (packet-udp.c:1274)
17  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac679c call_dissector_work + 316
18  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac6612 dissector_try_uint_new + 98 (packet.c:1451)
19  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000108f444fd ip_try_dissect + 157 (packet-ip.c:1817)
20  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000108f672bc ipv6_dissect_next + 284 (packet-ipv6.c:2609)
21  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000108f68389 dissect_ipv6 + 2809 (packet-ipv6.c:2559)
22  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac679c call_dissector_work + 316
23  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac6933 dissector_try_uint + 99 (packet.c:1451)
24  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000108d836a7 dissect_ethertype + 631 (packet-ethertype.c:296)
25  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac679c call_dissector_work + 316
26  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac5376 call_dissector_with_data + 38 (packet.c:3284)
27  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000108d82829 dissect_eth_common + 1449 (packet-eth.c:579)
28  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000108d82263 dissect_eth + 371 (packet-eth.c:884)
29  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac679c call_dissector_work + 316
30  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000108dc3f44 dissect_frame + 6596 (packet-frame.c:938)
31  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac679c call_dissector_work + 316
32  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac5376 call_dissector_with_data + 38 (packet.c:3284)
33  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ac5250 dissect_record + 784 (packet.c:626)
34  libwireshark.15.dylib           0x0000000109ab9f96 epan_dissect_run_with_taps + 70 (epan.c:644)
35  org.wireshark.Wireshark         0x00000001081cd86d add_packet_to_packet_list + 173
36  org.wireshark.Wireshark         0x00000001081c7b9d read_record + 413 (file.c:1297)
37  org.wireshark.Wireshark         0x00000001081c889b cf_continue_tail + 795 (file.c:840)
38  org.wireshark.Wireshark         0x00000001081cf8d0 capture_input_new_packets + 80 (capture.c:527)
39  org.wireshark.Wireshark         0x00000001081f3089 sync_pipe_input_cb + 921
40  org.wireshark.Wireshark         0x0000000107f7dc42 MainWindow::pipeActivated(int) + 50
41  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000111b7f5ec 0x11195b000 + 2246124
42  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000111b87dbd QSocketNotifier::event(QEvent*) + 669
43  org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x000000011063ac0d QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 269
44  org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x000000011063bfd2 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 466
45  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000111b4d234 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 212
46  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000111ba1df7 0x11195b000 + 2387447
47  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2ca39ad8 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 1016
48  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2ca1ad31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
49  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2cad260c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 108
50  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2c9fdce0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
51  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2c9fd15d __CFRunLoopRun + 1293
52  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2c9fc9b7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
53  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2bcdcd96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
54  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2bcdcb06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
55  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2bcdc884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
56  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff29f8da73 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
57  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2a723e34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
58  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff29f82885 -[NSApplication run] + 764
59  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x000000011316883c 0x113130000 + 231484
60  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000111b493af QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 431
61  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000111b4d7c2 QCoreApplication::exec() + 130
62  org.wireshark.Wireshark         0x0000000107f46e4d main + 3373
63  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff548d2015 start + 1"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is causing wireshark to crash and how can I stop it from crashing. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Error message says

`Dyld Error Message: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin Referenced from: /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libgcrypt.20.dylib (which was built for **Mac OS X 11.0**) Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`

you are running OS 10..?

To fix the problem

open and run the “Uninstall
ChmodBPF” package, then open and run “Install ChmodBPF” in order to
reset the ChmodBPF Launch Daemon

Comment: The crash report statement that it was made for MacOS X 11.0 is not true! The wireshark download centre states wireshark 3.6.21 is for Macos 10.  A 3rd Party is gaining remote access to the MacBook and presumably is responsible for creating that misleading statement!

Comment: open and run the “Uninstall
  ChmodBPF” package, then open and run “Install ChmodBPF” in order to
  reset the ChmodBPF Launch Daemon